# How to draw a gradiational color pattern on graph?

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory, physics

I'm going to plot a chladni a figure with color graph .
But the graph I made wasn't a gradiation color pattern.

do you know how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
  return -2*np.cos(8*np.pi*x/0.8)*np.cos(2*np.pi*(y+0.4)/0.8) -2*np.cos(6*np.pi*x/0.8)*np.cos(4*np.pi*(y+0.4)/0.8)

x = np.linspace(0, 0.8, 100)
y = np.linspace(-0.4, 0.4, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z= f(X, Y)


fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='jet')
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[the graph I made it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42glW.png)

[the ideal graph I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsfuM.png)
[the source](https://misaki-yuyyuyu.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/21/105554)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the levels parameter of *contourf* as follow :

```
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='jet',levels=100)
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html